Recursively find index of largest element in an array
So I’m working on this question that’s ask me to use recursion to make a method that returns the index of the largest element in an array of ints using this header “private static int findLargest (int [] items, int first, int last)”. This is what I wrote and while it does works as intended it gives a StackOverflowError if I feed it an array higher then 5 elements.
    private static int findLargest (int [] items, int first, int last) {
    
    if (first == last) {
        
        return first;
    
    }//end if
    
    if (last - 1 == first) {
        
        if (items[first] > items[last]) {
            
            return  first;
            
        } else {
            
            return last;
            
        }//end if
    
    }//end if
    
    int firstHalf = findLargest (items, first, last / 2);
    int secondHalf = findLargest(items, last / 2 + 1, last);
    
    if (items[firstHalf] > items[secondHalf]) {
        
        return firstHalf;
    
    } else {
    
        return secondHalf;
    
    }//end if
    
}//end method findLargest


BTW simpler recursive solution if (first == last) return first; int i = findLargest(items, first+1, last); return items[first]>items[i] ? first : i;

You are not dividing the given range correctly with last / 2, which may lead to last getting a value that is less than first, and this leads to infinite recursion.
Change this:
int firstHalf = findLargest (items, first, last / 2);
int secondHalf = findLargest(items, last / 2 + 1, last);

to this:
int mid = (first + last) / 2;
int firstHalf = findLargest (items, first, mid);
int secondHalf = findLargest(items, mid + 1, last);

